# Create a ListBox in Excel using Perl

Tags: excel, perl, listbox

I have a excel spreadsheet that I've created with Perl (Excel::Writer::XLSX) and I'm needing to add a ListBox, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The module does provide a framwork to use vba

from the doc
"An example of adding macros to an Excel::Writer::XLSX file using a VBA project file extracted from an existing Excel xlsm file.

The extract_vba utility supplied with Excel::Writer::XLSX can be used to extract the vbaProject.bin file."

An embedded macro is connected to a form button on the worksheet.

Take a look at [marco](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Examples.pm#Example:_macros.pl)